# NoReverseMatch at /accounts/password-reset/ for Password Reset in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-authentication

## Error- In Django after submitting email in "password-reset" page, I am getting this error.

> **NoReverseMatch at /accounts/password-reset/ Reverse for 'password_reset_done' not found. 'password_reset_done' is not a valid
>   view function or pattern name.**

---

**My Code in urls.py file-**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^password-reset/',
        auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(
            template_name='accounts/password_reset.html'),
        name='password_reset'),

    url(r'^password-reset/done/',
        auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(
            template_name='accounts/password_reset_done.html'),
        name='password_reset_done'),

    url(r'^password-reset-confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/',
        auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(
            template_name='accounts/password_reset_confirm.html'),
        name='password_reset_confirm'),
]
```

I also created separate HTML files for all pages in "accounts" directory.
By the way, I am following this tutorial on youtube - [click here](https://youtu.be/-tyBEsHSv7w)

[Url.py Code Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLCXs.png)

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSXVI.png)

[password_reset.html Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4U2s.png)

[password_reset_done.html Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3GGX.png)

[password_reset_confirm.html screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2YCg.png)

Github: [Click Here](https://github.com/Dipeshpal/Dipesh-Pal-Django-Website)

Answer (score 0):

How does the `.html` for `url(r'^password-reset/done/',...)` look like?

Comment: Review my post (question), I update it with my all screenshot. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you have included these views and templates inside of a separate django app called `accounts`.  When you separate views and routes into a separate app, [all of the route names that you specified will be namespaced](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/#introduction).

> URL namespaces allow you to uniquely reverse named URL patterns even if different applications use the same URL names. It’s a good practice for third-party apps to always use namespaced URLs (as we did in the tutorial). Similarly, it also allows you to reverse URLs if multiple instances of an application are deployed. In other words, since multiple instances of a single application will share named URLs, namespaces provide a way to tell these named URLs apart.

By default, the namespace assigned to those routes will be the application name (e.g., `accounts`) that you set in `urls.py`.  This means that the fully qualified names for the views that you have specified are `accounts:password_reset_done`, etc.  Thus, django cannot find the route / view that it is looking for which is the un-namespaced `password_reset_done`.

You can fix this by (1) moving your account login / password reset views to the `Dipesh_Pal` application and specifying the routes in `Dipesh_Pal/urls.py`, or (2) explicitly setting a namespace of `''` when including the `accounts.urls` in `Dipesh_Pal/urls.py`.

Comment: Would you please explain the method (2). How to "explicitly setting a namespace of '' when including the accounts.urls in Dipesh_Pal/urls.py"?

Comment: The referenced documentation offers several examples of explicitly setting a namespace.  Let me know if you still need help after you read it.